# JSX from Component in parent as a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that counts down from `5` and returns the current count in a JSX return.

Note: Normally I would use a function and use the returned value, however this is troublesome as the component uses React Hooks and causes an error when calling a function.

My countdown component is

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const countdownSeconds = 5;
const Countdown = () => {
  const [timing, setTiming] = useState(true);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(countdownSeconds);
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval: number;
    if (timing) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSecond(preSecond => {
          if (preSecond <= 1) {
            setTiming(false);
            clearInterval(interval);
            return countdownSeconds;
          } else {
            return preSecond - 1;
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timing]);

  return <>${timing ? second : 0}</>;
};

export default Countdown;
```

And I would like to use `<Countdown />` in the parent within a `string` inside the `props` of another component.

```
<Typography
  text={
    `countdown is` + <Countdown /> + `seconds`
  }
/>
```

This obviously returns `[object Object]`.

How can I get the `<>${timing ? second : 0}</>` as a string to pass to `<Typography />`?

I'd prefer not use `Context` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your code like this.

```
<Typography
  text={
    <>
      <span>countdown is</span> <Countdown /> <span>seconds</span>
    </>
  }
/>
```

Hope this will work for you!